# How to add Text to speech on retrieved Listview from sqlite in android java

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I retrieved data from sqlite and i need to add tts (text to speech) on each retrieved row but it does not work when i prees on listview to read listview items i retrieved in sqlite, please help me.

*My Java activity is this :*

```
 public class Favorites extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
ListView lv;
private  TextToSpeech tts;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor mCursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

DatabaseHelper mHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorite);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
    tts.setPitch(0.8f);
    tts.setSpeechRate(1.5f);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", DatabaseHelper.KEY_FAVORITE, DatabaseHelper.KEY_PRONOUNCIATION, DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT};
    mCursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.KEY_FAVORITE, DatabaseHelper.KEY_PRONOUNCIATION, DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT};
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,mCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}  );

    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    db.close();
    mCursor.close();
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}


@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // we check to see if text to speech is suppourted on the device
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(Favorites.this,
                "engine is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //If text to speech is not supported than we output an error message
    else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(Favorites.this,
                "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine probably you dont have it installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are doing nothing in 'onItemClick'

Comment: I added is in onclick but does not work    :  `  String  read=       DatabaseHelper.KEY_FAVORITE;  tts.speak(read, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);`

Comment: Make sure read String is not empty.